# What is that building in Suvarnabhumi Airport?

Tags: airport-design

In [Suvarnabhumi Airport](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Suvarnabhumi+Airport/@13.6919938,100.7516928,2106m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x311d67771542274f:0x120d19554f157a07) (Bangkok) there is a building in aerodrome, next to the main terminal (Circle by red colour) . What is that?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On page 5 of [current airport chart](http://www.aisthai.aviation.go.th/webais/pdf/AD%20vol1-CHART/VTBS[27].pdf) states it is Transfer Baggage Terminal

It was officially opened on 1 November 2014 and reduce baggage transfer time from 75 minutes to 60 minutes. It was constructed above South Airside Tunnel between gate C, D and E and has usable space of about 12,550 sq.m.

[Source](http://suvarnabhumiairport.com/en/news/448/%E0%B8%97%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A8%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B8%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%93%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B9%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%B4%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%94%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3-transfer-baggage-terminal-%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B3%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%9C%E0%B8%B9%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%82%E0%B8%94%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%AA%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%A2%E0%B8%A7%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%A7) (Sorry source is in Thai. My own translation.)

Another [source](http://www.mcot.net/site/content?id=5466dca0be0470b9cc8b472d#.VdAGcMsaySO) in English. Similar to my original source.